# How to Pulse an HTML Element

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to pulse (fadeout/fadein) an HTML element using a while loop while the mouse is hovering over the element, but the webpage keeps crashing when the .hover() event is triggered. I can't seem to identify the error in my code. Any help or alternative suggestions would be greatly appreciated. The code is as follows:

```
function pulse(selector) {
    var pulsing = true;
    while(pulsing) {
        $.when(
            $(selector)fadeOut(1000),
            $(selector)fadeIn(1000)
        ).done(function() {
            if(!$(selector).is(":hover")) {
                pulsing = false;
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Comment: I would guess the fadeIn/fadeOut calls are running in parallel and causing an infinite loop (am I transparent enough yet? Nope! Am I opaque enough yet? Nope!). You need to run them in series.

Comment: Wouldn't a plain css animation be sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really use while loops like this -- I think it goes "too fast" for those fades to catch up and overloads the browser.  In general (and it was something I was mistaken about when I first came to JS from other languages) you can't think of animated effects in JavaScript in terms of loops as you can in other languages.  Not to go off on a tangent, but for things that you do need to continuously update/"loop through" as the page is running, use setInterval().

In this case, I think the best/simplest thing might be to use a CSS animation for this, although obviously older versions of IE won't support it:

```
@keyframes pulse {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
   0% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.selector {
   /*-- whatever --*/
}

.selector:hover {
   animation: pulse 0.5s infinite;
   -webkit-animation: pulse 0.5s infinite;
}
```

Here's that as a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Wbx2/

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Yeah, I'm just getting into web stuff with a background mostly in hardware. Been an interesting change of pace. Thanks for your help and insight!

Comment: No problem!  Yeah, when I first came to JS I tried to use loops like this too, since in many languages you do need a loop running to have "live updating" events.  If this did work to solve the problem, could you go ahead and mark it as solved?  Thanks!